# trying to delay using setTimeout() in a while loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop, settimeout, delay

basically im trying to make an automation script for a gambling website . if you know roulette game mode you would now that you have about 20 seconds to choose a color and 10 seconds for the outcome to appear each round . what im trying to do is making a while loop for the script to run until the balance reaches a certain amount . what im struggling with is using the set timeout function to make a delay every 30 seconds so the betting bot can bet each round basically it waits 30 seconds then the bot bets .
example :

```
do{
    delay 30 seconds amount 
    run bot()
}while(condition)
```

when i tried to use the set timeout function and used the script on the website its started betting infinitely and the whole thing crashed because the delay didn't happen correctly.
this is the code :

```
function Bot(bt, bc)
{

  l = ((document.getElementsByClassName("roulette-past-queue--previous-rolls-container horizontal-scroll")[0].innerText).length);
  f = document.getElementsByClassName("roulette-past-queue--previous-rolls-container horizontal-scroll")[0].innerText;
  number = f[l - 1];
  number = parseInt(number.replace(" ", ""));
  if (number >= 1 && number <= 7)
  {
    LastResult = "red";
  }
  if (number >= 8 && number <= 14)
  {
    LastResult = "black";
  }
  if (number == 0)
  {
    LastResult = "green";
  }
  if (LastResult == bc)
  {
    if (bc == "red")
    {
      document.getElementById('bet-input-r').value = bt;
      document.getElementById('roulette-btn-red').click();
    }
    else
    {
      document.getElementById('bet-input-r').value = bt;
      document.getElementById('roulette-btn-black').click();
    }

  }
  if (LastResult != bc)
  {
    if (bc == "red")
    {
      document.getElementById('bet-btn-double-r').click();
      document.getElementById('roulette-btn-black').click();
      bc = "black"
        bt = bt * 2

    }
    else
    {
      document.getElementById('bet-btn-double-r').click();
      document.getElementById('roulette-btn-red').click();
      bc = "red"
        bt = bt * 2
    }
  }

}

balance = document.getElementById('balance').innerHTML;
balance = parseInt(balance.replace(",", ""));
bet = 10
  TargetBalance = 99988
  document.getElementById('bet-input-r').value = bet;
betcolor = "black";
if (betcolor == "red")
{
  document.getElementById('roulette-btn-red').click();
}
else
{
  document.getElementById('roulette-btn-black').click();
}
//this is the looping part causing the problem i have deleted setTimout so you can see what i mean clearly
do
{
  // 30 seconds delay
  Bot(bet, betcolor)

}
while (balance < TargetBalance && balance > bet)
```

Comment: use an iife and pass it the timing `(plusSecond) => {setTimeout(() => {}, 1000*plusSecond)}(iteration++)`, though your need to manage the timer in the while

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: Can you be so kind to create a more basic example, at least citing `setTimeout` once? It would be simpler to help you to understand how to use `setTimeout`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the simplest way, but you would have to remove the loop, otherwise, you will get gazzilion calls. Add this check at the end of your `Bot` function.

```
  if(balance < TargetBalance && balance > bet) {
      setTimeout(() => {
          Bot(bet, betcolor)
      }, 30000); // Expects ms, so 1000 * 30
  }
```

There is another way using `async/await`. First create a delay function:

```
function delay(){
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
         setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1000)
    });
}
```

And afterwards, use await on it. Note that to use it, the scope has to be async.

```
async function main() {
    for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         console.log(i);
         await delay();
    }
}
```

Comment: thats the problem the loop is essential for the script so it can keep running

Comment: The first one, will call `Bot` only once, but not every 30 seconds ...

Comment: @derpirscher If that piece of code is placed inside of `Bot` it will.

Answer (score 0):

In principle there are at least three possiblities

1. using `async/await`

Make the surrounding scope `async` and then `await` a Promise that resolves after a given period of time

```
async fun doTheLoop() {
  do {
    await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 30000)); //the promise resolves after 30 seconds
    Bot(bet, betcolor);
  } while (balance < TargetBalance && balance > bet)
}

doTheLoop();
```

2. using [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

```
function callTheBot() {
   Bot(bet, betcolor);

   if (balance < TargetBalance && balance > bet)
     setTimeout(callTheBot(), 30000);
}

setTimeout(callTheBot, 30000);
```

3. Using [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) and cancel the interval when the condition is not met anymore

```
let interval = setInterval(() => {
  if (balance < TargetBalance && balance > bet) {
    Bot(bet, betcolor);
  } else {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
},30000);
```

Comment: i see that you got rid of the while loop and the first didn't even execute

Comment: Yes I got rid of the while loop, because it's not possible using a while loop. And what do you mean by "didn't even execute"? Did you even call the function? All three of these posibilities will call `Bot(...)` once every 30 seconds, while the condition is met.

Comment: oh sorry i just copied and pasted it .

Comment: thnx for your help ur first suggestion worked perfectly

Comment: please don't forget to accept/upvote if the anwer helped you